# I have written a sorting algorithm. Is this a quicksort?

Tags: python, sorting

Is this a quicksort? If I have an array `A=[1,43,21,45,56,7]`, I check the last element with first,second,third to last-1 and swap if last element is less with the compared values. Then I proceed to do the process starting from 2nd element going up to last-1 and comparing with the last element? I continue to do this with third, fourth and last-1.

```
#quicksort
def qsort(li):
    end=len(li)-1
    for i in range(len(li)):
        begin=0
        print begin
        while (begin<end):
            if li[begin]>li[end]:
                temp=li[begin]
                li[begin]=li[end]
                li[end]=temp
            begin+=1
        end-=1


    return li
```

Comment: No.  It's more like a selection sort.

Comment: note that you do not need your `temp` variable, thanks to pythons awesome `a,b = b,a` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments, this is not a Quicksort. What you are doing is selecting the end element, making a comparison for each of the other values and then swapping values based on this. Despite using a reference point similar to a "pivot" in a Quicksort, you are not using it to split the list on both higher and lower comparisons (only lower).

If you do wish to write a Quicksort instead, I thoroughly recommend the recursive model instead of an iterative one. You would pick a pivot element and then sort into two new lists depending on whether the element is larger or smaller and then run the function on these new lists. Finally, rejoin the lists in order of: smaller, pivot, larger.

Comment: So what i did is the worst case scenario of quicksort?

Comment: Refer to @Freestyle076 above. You have not technically done a quicksort, and it is indeed worse computationally (in terms of time complexity). Note, however we have the traditional trade-off where you have lower space complexity as you are not storing subsequent smaller copies of the lists.

Answer (score 2):

As Ian and Peter say, it seems to be a combination of bubble sort and selection sort due to the swapping and maintenance of an order list on one end of the array. DEFINITELY not quicksort - which has complexity O(nlogn) - this algorithm has complexity O(n^2)... for every n elements you make n comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

**That's a selection sort**,
 where you compare each element with the rest of the succeeding element and find the least(ascending) or greatest(descending) and swap with that element
.i.e we select the least/greatest element and swap and proceed with next element

However, quicksort is recursive in nature and partitions are done.

Comment: Is there any advantage of doing partition rather than just doing the sort as I have done?

Comment: @277roshan: Yes; partitioning properly yields O(N log N) asymptotic run time, but your sort is O(N^2) asymptotic run time.  This matters when N reaches a few hundred entries, typically, sometimes quicker than that.

Comment: Can u tell me what log(n2) time complexity means. O(n) is going through the list once. O(logn) is halving the list each time. So what is an analogous statement?

Comment: @277roshan It is a different question, so ask this as a new question. If you get a good answer, accept that by clicking on the green pipe icon on the left side. Asking a new question instead of it is evil.